# How to analyze a file using the TextRazor library for Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is the code:

```
client = textrazor.TextRazor(extractors=["entities", "topics"])
response = client.analyze("bla bla")
for entity in response.entities():
    print(entity.id, entity.relevance_score, entity.confidence_score, entity.freebase_types)
```

I need to analyze a file instead of a part of text, is it possible with TextRazor?

Comment: You can analyze a URL, but I don't see an option for a file [in the docs](https://www.textrazor.com/docs/python#analysis)

Comment: Yes it's only for URL or String thks for your help